# Guice child injector override binding

Tags: java, guice

I am trying to to override a binding in a child injector that was already configured in a base injector.

like that :

```
public class PersistenceModule extends Abstract{

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(IProductPersistenceHelper.class).to(ProductPersistenceHelper.class);
    }
}
```

then :

```
Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new PersistenceModule());
injector.createChildInjector(new AbstractModule(){
        @Override
        protected void configure() {
            bind(IProductPersistenceHelper.class).to(MockProductPersistenceHelper.class);
        }

})
```

Guice is complaining that it has already a binding for that. Are there any patterns or best practices for that problem ?